Serial TTL communication with Nikon SLRs
I have a Nikon F6 and I'm looking to communicate with it similarly to how products like Meta35 used to. I'm very experienced with electronics and don't foresee an issue getting serial TTL communication from my computer to the camera (via the accessory terminal and a TTL-USB adapter).
Are there any resources out there describing the communication protocol for Nikon cameras (F90, F100, F5, F6, potentially DSLRs) that have communication possibilities through the accessory terminal (not direct USB).
TIA.
